# Block images link to colorbox of clicked image on new page

Tags: media, javascript

I want to have an **Images Block**, which when an image is clicked, links to a **gallery page** with the clicked image opened in **colorbox**. I'm using **drupal 7**.

Comment: Have you created any content type that contains the image?

Comment: And please explain this "links to a gallery page" in your question. Or you can edit your question to explain your problem in detail